# Hosting Angular fullstack project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, yeoman-generator-angular

I started a new Yeoman angular-fullstack project (client-angular.js, server-node.js)
(generator: https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack)
I have 2 seperated directories for client and server,
I want to launch the app but the deployment don't show any index.html file,

The question is, Should I make 2 different hosts for the server and the client?
if no, how can I host and use the united projects?

Comment: No, they're both part of your single project. The "client" directory just means that there's stuff in it that more or less gets rendered/served as is to the client, like your client-side javascript code or your styles or templates.

Comment: Can you give me and advise where and how can I host it? after grunt build? would be very helpful and great answer

Comment: I assume you have it working on localhost? Heroku is the popular choice to host node.js projects online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not needed to create 2 different hosts for the server.
The server needs to point to `app.js`, usually located at `server/app.js`, as this is the entry point (instead of index.html) of your app. *How* this is done depends solely on the server you intend on using.

If you consider using IIS you can take a look at: [Installing and Running node.js applications within IIS on Windows](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx)

As for the other deployment options, as [laggingreflex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1266650/laggingreflex) said, *"Heroku is the popular choice to host node.js projects"*. The angular-fullstack git site has more information on deploying to Heroku or Openshift.

As a side note:

Deploying to IIS requires a bit more attention than the information in the link specified. You need to set file access, create a `web.config` file as well as a few other stuff. At least, I had to...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a host that supports MongoDB assuming you kept the Database the same after generating your application.  Heroku is a great option as it allows you to setup up plugins like mongolab or mongohq fairly easily.  I would also recommend looking into Digital Ocean as they allow you to set up a droplet/server that has what you need for the application to run.

If you go with Digital Ocean and are a student check out https://education.github.com/pack.  You'll actually receive $100 credit towards a new Digital Ocean account which will let you test things out.

Good luck!